# Problem with fork () and shared memory in c

Tags: c

I have a problem with my code in C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#define SIZE 1024
#define KEY 0x1234

typedef struct{
  int sharedNum;
  int counter1;
  int counter2;
} SharedMem;

int main (void) {
  SharedMem *memory;
  int shmid;
  if ((shmid=shmget(KEY, SIZE, 0644 | IPC_CREAT))==-1) {
    perror ("shmget error!");
    exit (1);
  }
  else {
    memory=shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    if (memory==(void*)-1) {
      perror ("shamt error!");
      exit (1);
    }
    else {
      memory->sharedNum=1;
    }
  }
  int procPID = fork();
  for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    if (fork()==0) {
      printf ("Forking in for-cyklus\n");
      exit (0);
    }
  }
  if (shmdt(memory)==-1) {
    perror ("shmdt error!");
    exit (-1);
  }
  if (shmctl (shmid, IPC_RMID, 0)==-1) {
    perror ("shmctl error!");
    exit (1);
  }
  return 0;
```

I'm waiting, that I will see this text "Forking in for-cyklus\n" 5 times, but i see this 10 times. When i delete piece of code with creating shared memory it works correctly. But in the end, i need this shared memory for the next functions. Do you have any idea, why it happens and how i may fix it?

Comment: This has nothing to do, whatsoever, with shared memory. Pop quiz: after the following line: `int procPID = fork();` -- how many different processes do you think will be executing the immediately-following `for` loop, the one that creates five child processes?

Answer (score 0):

In `int procPID = fork();` you create a second process, so you now have *two* processes running which proceed into the next loop, which is:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
  if (fork()==0) {
    printf ("Forking in for-cyklus\n");
    exit (0);
  }
}
```

Thus, `if (fork()==0) {` is executed 10 times - five times in each process resulting from `int procPID = fork();`, as it isn't limited to running in either the parent or child process - and your message is printed 10 times.